# Sesiones en php para determinado usuario

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, session

Buen dia estoy trabajando en WampServer php y mysql con sesiones tengo un problema al tener muchos usuarios quiero que cuando inicie sesion muestre los datos solo de ese usuario, mi problema es como asignar un id para que cuando inicie abra con los datos solo de ese usuario. Tengo dos tablas Usuario y esta relacionada con el campo id usuario a la tabla alumnos quiero sea la misma página para  todos los usuarios alumnos  y únicamente cambie la información a visualizar, tengo entendido que con SQL JOIN pero nunca lo he uasado.

```
$alumnos = mysql_query(“SELECT * FROM alumnos WHERE alumno = ‘$usuario’ AND password = ‘$password'”);
if(mysql_num_rows($alumno) > 0)
{
session_start();
$_SESSION[‘alumno’]=”$usuario”, $id;

header(“Location: alumnos/espacioalumno.php”);

exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes guardar todas las variables que quieras en la varible $_SESSION, es decir:

`$_SESSION['alumno'] = $usuario;
 $_SESSION['id'] = $id;`

despues haces un echo:

`echo $_SESSION['alumno'] . ' ' . $_SESSION['id'];`

si quieres cogerlos de la base de datos te hara falta tambien hacer un mysqli_fetch_array o algo asi para capturar los datos de la consulta.

Comment: Tal vez no me explique bien pero esa era mi pregunta compañero como hacer que me muestre los datos solo de ese alumno al iniciar sesion con su usuario.

Comment: Tienes que tomar los datos de la consulta a la base de datos con un fetch. Por ejemplo: $ resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($alumnos); despues: echo $resultado['nombre'] . $resultado['id'] o como sea que se llamen tus columnas en la base de datos. Pero si haces un header location no veras los datos porque te redirige a la pagina anterior si quieres que te los muestre sin recargar la pagina tienes que usar Ajax. Te sirvió?